# How to link personal webpage on parse.com?

Tags: email, parse-platform, html

I want to link my personal webpage on [parse.com](http://parse.com/), so that I can implement the `verify_email_success.html` file. But I don't find a text field where this works.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to first sign up at Parse.com and then create a new application (which will represent your website).

From quick Googling, I've found this tutorial which looks to focus on the type of thing you are trying to do:

http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/05/17/adding-email-verification-to-the-parse-com-sign-up-process/

**UPDATE:**

From looking into this a bit more, it appears that Parse.com works very much like many other web-based services/APIs, in that to "link" your application (website in your case) with Parse.com, you need to specify the **Application Key** that Parse provides when you create a new application via their website.

**Untested example based on Parse.com documentation:**

```
Parse.initialize("APPLICATION ID", "JAVASCRIPT KEY");
```

Source: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#social/web/new